# changing a single value using v-model / full table is redrawn

Tags: vue.js, data-binding, v-model

I was building an editable table, which began to crawl to a halt when the number of rows started to run in the 100's. This led me to investigate what was going on.

In the example below, when changing the value in the input, the whole table is redrawn, and the `ifFunction()` function is trigged 4 times.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't Vue be capable of just redrawing the respective cell? Have I done something wrong with the key-binding?

```
<template>
    <div id="app">

        <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
            <tr v-for="(row, rowKey) in locations" :key="`row_+${rowKey}`">
                <td v-for="(column, columnKey) in row" :key="`row_+${rowKey}+column_+${columnKey}`">
                    <span v-if="ifFunction()">{{ column }}</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <input v-model="locations[0][1]">

    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {

        data() {
            return {
                locations: [
                    ["1","John"],
                    ["2","Jake"]
                ], // TODO : locations is not generic enough.
            }
        },

        methods: {
            ifFunction() {
                console.log('ifFunction');
                return true;
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` property defines reactive elements - if you change one part of it, everything that's depending on that piece of `data` will be recalculated.

You can use `computed` properties to "cache" values, and only update those that really need updating.

I rebuilt your component so computed properties can be used throughout: created a `cRow` and a `cCell` component ("custom row" and "custom cell") and built back the table from these components. The row and the cell components each have a computed property that "proxies" the `prop` to the template - thus also caching it.

On first render you see the `ifFunction()` four times (this is the number of cells you have based on the `data` property in **Vue** instance), but if you change the value with the input field, you only see it once (for every update; you may have to click "Full page" to be able to update the value).

```js
Vue.component('cCell', {
  props: {
    celldata: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    isInput: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true
    },
    coords: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      normalCellData: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
    normalCellData: {
      handler: function(value) {
        this.$emit('cellinput', {
          coords: this.coords,
          value
        })
      },
      immediate: false
    }
  },
  template: `<td v-if="ifFunction()"><span v-if="!isInput">{{normalCellData}}</span> <input v-else type="text" v-model="normalCellData" /></td>`,
  methods: {
    ifFunction() {
      console.log('ifFunction');
      return true;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.normalCellData = this.celldata
  }
})
Vue.component('cRow', {
  props: {
    rowdata: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    },
    rownum: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  template: `
  <tr>
    <td
      is="c-cell"
      v-for="(item, i) in rowdata"
      :celldata="item"
      :is-input="!!(i % 2)"
      :coords="[i, rownum]"
      @cellinput="reemit"
     ></td>
  </tr>`,
  methods: {
    reemit(data) {
      this.$emit('cellinput', data)
    }
  }
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    locations: [
      ["1", "John"],
      ["2", "Jake"]
    ], // TODO : locations is not generic enough.
  },
  methods: {
    updateLocations({
      coords,
      value
    }) {
      // creating a copy of the locations data attribute
      const loc = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.locations))
      loc[coords[1]][coords[0]] = value
      // changing the whole locations data attribute to preserve
      // reactivity
      this.locations = loc
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(row, i) in locations" is="c-row" :rowdata="row" :rownum="i" @cellinput="updateLocations"></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- <input v-model="locations[0][1]">
  <input v-model="locations[1][1]">-->
  {{locations}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Muka, that works like a charm. I am new to Vue and had not touched components yet, although I knew that was coming :-)

If you could point me in the right direction with the following question, that would be much appreciated:

If I wanted to add an <input> to the <td> .. </td> and then "v-model" it to the respective value in the "locations" dataset, how would I do that? Is that data even accessible from within the components?

Comment: @TjeerdKramer like you would like to add an inline edit box to a table cell's value?

Comment: **Vue** offers a nice way to "bubble up" events to parent components (or grandparent, etc), and it's called **emit**ting an event. `$emit()` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html So, if you want to change the data of a parent component (from a child component), you have to **emit** an event (with the data as payload) and "catch" it where you want to handle it (up the component tree). Other solutions could be using an **event bus** or even a state management tool (like **Vuex**) - but these might be a little overkill if you want to only do this in one place.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it.

As for your first answer, is the "computed" bit really needed? I that replacing `{{computedData}}` with `{{celldata}}` works too?

Comment: @TjeerdKramer you can try using data property (not much of a hassle to do that) - but you’re supposed to see that render 4 times on every modification - it’s not the component structure that prevents the update, but the computed attribute. The computed attributes update only when the value they depend on update - actually caching the value.

Comment: It does not render 4 times when I change it, still just once... Now... Let me dive into the subject of emitting events. I need to "bind" an <input> in the c-cell component to the respective value to the `locations` data, which is "in" the grandparent...

Comment: @TjeerdKramer then maybe the `props` do not get recalculated - and thus not passed down.

Comment: @TjeerdKramer you chose something quite complex to start with `$emit`... the grandchild emits the value, the parent reemits, the grandparent catches... but it works with my edited answer snippet:)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your efforts! There's actually something easier than your re-emit solution: `v-on="$listeners"`

Comment: @TjeerdKramer - yes, I did the old-fashioned way :)